# passing viewController as a parameter in function

Tags: swift, xcode, function

I want to pass viewController type as a function just like the code below

```swift
extension UIViewController {
    func switchScreen(storyboardName:String,viewControllerName:String,vcc:UIViewController) {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerName) as? vcc {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

but xcode returns an error that says `Cannot find type 'vcc' in scope`

I tried adding `.Type` in the parameter after `UIViewController` but the error is the same.
any solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The third parameter must be a type, not an instance

```
extension UIViewController {
    func switchScreen<T : UIViewController>(storyboardName: String, viewControllerName: String, type: T.Type) {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerName) as? T {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

and call it

```
switchScreen(storyboardName: "Main", 
             viewControllerName: "Foo", 
             type: LoginViewController.self)
```

But as `instantiateViewController` and also `present` don't care about the static type you don't need it, this is sufficient

```
extension UIViewController {
    func switchScreen(storyboardName: String, viewControllerName: String) {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerName)
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

---

To avoid a crash you could add an enum with the available view controller identifiers and pass this type in the second parameter for example

```
enum ControllerIdentifier : String, RawRepresentable {
    case foo, bar
}

extension UIViewController {
    func switchScreen(storyboardName: String, viewControllerName: ControllerIdentifier) {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerName.rawValue)
        self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use generic param

```
extension UIViewController {
    func switchScreen<T: UIViewController>(storyboardName:String,viewControllerName:String,vcc:T) {
        let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: Bundle.main)
        if let viewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: viewControllerName) as? T {
            self.present(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I call that function because whenever I try to call it anywhere it returns an error `Instance method 'switchScreen(storyboardName:viewControllerName:vcc:)' requires that 'LoginViewController.Type' inherit from 'UIViewController'`